# Titanium appcelerator : window focus event not triggered when returning from other window

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have recently started development with titanium appcelerator for developing Android application. And got stuck in a problem that seems to be very minor issues for other who are well versed with Titanium but it have created a headache for me being a beginner.

I have two window named **main** and **subwindow**.On button click i am redirected to **subwindow** from **main** window. Now whenever I am pressing back button on emulator from **subwindow**. I have written logic for closing current window i.e **subwindow** so that I can view **main** window. That works fine even **subwindow** closes successfully and even I can view **main** window. But now if I am trying to click button in **main** window that doesn't happen.

Even I tried to catch focus event in **main** window that happens when application is initially loaded but when i am in **subwindow** and closing **subwindow**,  file focus event is not triggered in **main** window.

HERE GOES MY CODE

**APP.JS**

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    backgroundColor:'black'
});

var btngo=Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : "Go !!!!",
    top : "30%"
});

var lbltitle=Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : "This is home page",
    font : {fontSize : "20%"} ,
    top : "20%",
    color : 'white'
});

//Event listener for adding clicking event
btngo.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var nextwindow=Ti.UI.createWindow({
        url : "window.js"   
    });
    nextwindow.open();
});
win1.addEventListener('focus',function(e)
{
    alert("main window focused");
});
win1.addEventListener('android:back', function (e) 
{
  win1.close();
});
win1.add(lbltitle);
win1.add(btngo);
win1.open();
```

**WINDOW.JS**

```
var childwindow=Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : "white"
});


var btnhome=Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : "HOME PAGE"
});


var lbltitle=Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : "This is child window",
    font : {fontSize : "20%"} ,
    top : "20%",
    color : 'white'
});
//For adding event listener for detecting click on home page button
btnhome.addEventListener('click',function(e){
     childwindow.close();   
});

//Adding event listener for detcting back button click in android 
childwindow.addEventListener('android:back', function (e) {
  childwindow.close();
});

childwindow.add(lbltitle);
childwindow.add(btnhome);
childwindow.open();
```

Hope that I would get solution to my problem as soon as possible.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Please update your question with code sample. So that we can easily help you.

Comment: hey .how to add code. . .i am new to stack flow too. .can you help me out with that Anand. . .jst was searching the same. .

Comment: just click the edit link below question and append your code below, then select the code and click the '{}' symbol at top. You're done :)

Comment: please refer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks to know about code formatting

Comment: thanks Anand .jst check it out my code

Comment: Ya . . It have solved my issue. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an opening another window inside the window.js. Probably this is the problem. Try changing your `window.js` file as follows

```
var childwindow=Ti.UI.currentWindow;
childwindow.backgroundColor = 'white'; //You may specify the same while creating the window
var btnhome=Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : "HOME PAGE"
});


var lbltitle=Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : "This is child window",
    font : {fontSize : "20%"} ,
    top : "20%",
    color : 'white'
});
//For adding event listener for detecting click on home page button
btnhome.addEventListener('click',function(e){
     childwindow.close();   
});

//Adding event listener for detcting back button click in android 
childwindow.addEventListener('android:back', function (e) {
  childwindow.close();
});

childwindow.add(lbltitle);
childwindow.add(btnhome);
```

Hope this will do the trick :)

Comment: i have tried the above given code. it gives an error. .   Exception occurred at window.js:2: Uncaught ReferenceError: childWindow is not defined

Comment: I just tried removing childWindow.backgroundColor = 'white';. executed but here window is being overlapped. I can see content of app.js and window.js in single window

Comment: Please see the updated code. There was a spelling mistake in the code. The window are overlapped becuase the new window's backgroundcolor is transparent. You can set it either as above or while creating the new window in app.js as `Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:'white', url:'window.js'});`

Comment: Thanks a lot Anand. It has worked great for me. Finally a big issue that I was facing since last 4 - 5 days comes to an end. All bcoz of you. THANK U VERY MUCH ANAND. U are genious.

Comment: Okay, thanks. By accepting the answer, SO means the answer resolved your issue. And it may be helpful for someone else